# Issue while using VLfeat's vl_kdforest_query_with_array

Tags: multicore, vlfeat

I am trying to use VlFeat's vl_kd_forest_query and vl_kdforest_query_with_array. The documentation is poor. All it says is that vl_kdforest_query_with_array "can" make use of multiple cores for running. Does anyone know if this function already uses multiple cores or is there a way to make use of it? Thanks!

(I know one option is to go through the code, but just wanted to know if anyone already has this information.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function uses parallelization via OpenMP as you can see [here](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/350c4f0/vl/kdtree.c#L898-L900):

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp for
#endif
for(qi = 0 ; qi < (signed)numQueries; ++ qi) {
    /* ... */
}
```